# Powershell Import-CSV how to skip until particular line based on string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Hi My CSV file is like this

```
#BEGINPROPERTIES
total.candidate.create=2
duration=0:00:00.433
internal.audit.session.id=1397055568
internal.cluster.node.info=(product:enterprise,id:node796599_796601,http:"10.111.233.79:19788",jgroups:"chprapk11406-44186",contextPath:/enterprise,isCoordinator:false)
processing.batching.size=1
total.candidate=2
non.updatable.fields=error.different
internal.cluster.node.id=node796599_796601
progress.interval=1
CSVLineCount=2
default.operation=merge
total.status.error=2
#ENDPROPERTIES
"Index","Identifier","Status","TransactionType","Result","Message"
"1","Candidate|create|224568907","error","candidate.create",,"The following email address is already used by a candidate included in the database: landers.samantha@target.com.;"
```

While importing CSV in powershell, I need to consider only from Column name ( "Index") and need to skip till #ENDPROPERTIES". There are no defined count for lines as each time the count may vary but every time I need to skip until "#ENDPROPERTIES".
How do I achieve that?

Comment: You could determine the line number of `#ENDPROPERTIES` with a `Select-String`, Import the content of the CSV with a `Get-Content`, Skip the line until the line number you now already know and convert the text to CSV with a `ConvertTo-Csv`.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) My problem is the line number is not constant. For example, Some times I get #ENDPROPERTIES at 16th line sometimes I get it at 18. How do I skip based on string without considering line number?

Comment: That's why you should determine it with a `Select-String`!  ;-)

Comment: Got it now, thanks :)

Comment: Instead of appending **Solved** to the question title, simply click the check mark next to the answer that solved your problem. This lets others know your issue is resolved. For more information, please visit the [help].

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I checked it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$csvpath = "C:\deleteme.csv"
$csvContent = Get-Content -Path $csvpath 
$LineNumber = $csvContent | Select-String '#ENDPROPERTIES' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LineNumber'
$csvData = $csvContent | Select-Object -Skip $LineNumber | ConvertFrom-Csv
```